# How to add BETA symbol at bootstrap Navbar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to add a "BETA" symbol at top of the "Brand Name" like "TM" symbol in my Navbar how can I do that..?

Comment: share ur code here

Comment: If you're referring to **β** it is techincally a character from the greek alphabet and you can add it like any other character. You can even copy and paste from this comment into any decent text editor.

Comment: @JonP  I want to add like "BETA" .

Comment: There is not "BETA" symbol in that case. Do you mean literally the word BETA, just smaller and raised a little? `<sup>BETA</sup>` will then work for you. You may need to adjust styling to your needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use css to achieve this, and when you copy the text it won't get copied!

```css
h1::after {
   content: 'BETA';
   font-size: 12px;
   vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<h1>StackOverflow</h1>
```